# Пропустить строку при чтении Си

Tags: c, файлы, формат

подскажите как можно пропустить строку с комментарием при чтении файла

```
struct obraz *wczytaj(char *nazwa) {

    struct obraz *obraz_we;
    char temp[100];
    int i, j;
    FILE *wsk;

    wsk = fopen(nazwa, "r");

    if (wsk == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nPlik nie istnieje\n\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fgets(temp, 99, wsk);
    fgets(temp, 99, wsk);
    obraz_we = (struct obraz *)malloc(sizeof(struct obraz));

    fscanf(wsk, "%d %d %d", &obraz_we->k, &obraz_we->w, &obraz_we->skala);//Записываем в структуры данные о количестве колонок
                                                                          //рядов и уровень серости
    printf("W naszej tablicy\nKolumn %d\nWierszy %d\n Siarosz na poziomie %d\n", obraz_we->k, obraz_we->w, obraz_we->skala);
                                                                          //obraz_we как указатель на структуру, k - ее поле
    obraz_we->piksel = (int**)calloc(obraz_we->w, sizeof(int*));
                                                                          //Декларация двухмерной таблицы
    for (i = 0; i < obraz_we->w; i++) {
        obraz_we->piksel[i] = (int*)calloc(obraz_we->k, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (j = 0; j < obraz_we->w; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < obraz_we->k; i++) {
            fscanf(wsk, "%d", &obraz_we->piksel[j][i]);                   
        }
    }
    return obraz_we;
}
```

читаю из файла pgm и в файле присутствуют комментарии (начинается с "#"), хочу чтобы при появлении комментария чтение перескакивало сразу на следующую строку.
Только, пожалуйста, напишите реализацию потому сам пробовал несколько способов и не идет что-то.

Comment: Покажите код чтения из файла. Приведённый вами код не имеет отношения к сути вопроса.

Comment: У вас в строке могут быть несколько чисел или по одному в строке?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил целую функцию

Comment: @Harry файл PGM в в одной строке много чисел

Comment: Привели бы маленький кусочек этого загадочного файла pgm, было бы нагляднее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не компилировал, просто идея. Получение очередного числа из файла

```
int getNextInt(FILE* f, int * errorCode)
{
    if (errorCode) *errorCode = 0;                 // Все Ok
    for(;;)
    {
        int val;
        if (fscanf(f,"%d",&val) == 1) return val;  // Все Ok
        val = fgetc(f);                            // Если нет...
        if (val == EOF)                            // Это конец файла?
        {
            if (errorCode) *errorCode = EOF;       // Устанавливаем флаг
            return 0;                              // Выход
        }
        if (val == '#')                            // Это комментарий?
        {
            while(val != EOF && val != '\n')       // Читаем до конца строки
                val = fgetc(f);                    // (иначе все равно никак...)
            continue;
        }
        if (errorCode) *errorCode = EOF;           // Тут - присвоить код неверного формата!!
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Примерно так. И проверять код ошибки.

Или - возвращать код ошибки, а считанное значение получать через указатель - может, так даже удобнее...

Answer (score 1):

Вот что я пока придумал, тут вместо файлов используется строка, но я думаю тут будет не сложно имплементировать считывание с файла.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *str = "This is normal line\n#but this is comment\nThis is normal line again! # with a comment\n";
    int size = 0;
    while (str[size] != '\0') size++; // Define size of a string


    bool commentFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '#')
        {
            commentFound = true;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '\n' && commentFound)
        {
            commentFound = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (!commentFound)
        {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если файл, то применение `fgets(...)` решит большую часть проблем с чтением строки, останется только сравнить символ строки с индексом `0` со знаком `#`

Comment: А если комментарий будет после строки? например так `This is a line #this is a comment` то ваш метод не сработает

Comment: @ishidex2 комментарий может быть только вначале строки

Comment: Ну тогда @NewView прав.

Comment: @ishidex2 да я понимаю что так можно, но туповат видно,  не могу втулить это что-бы работало, потому попросил что-бы показали как это применить

Comment: Ну писать полноценный парсер даже комментов не так просто, надо учесть все нюансы включая табуляцию :) так что для простого решения - простые методы.

Comment: @NewView и не решит проблемы, если в строке может быть разное количество чисел, например...

Comment: ммм.. я видимо что то пропустил про длинну строки, с цифрами. Речь вроде о том как отрезать комменты?